# Why show error in mysql result consisted of more than one row?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I show many question and answer in stackoverflow,but i cannot find solution such type of problem

```
USE `student`;  
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `useOUT`;  
DELIMITER $$ USE`student`$$ CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  PROCEDURE `useOUT`(in in_name varchar(15),out in_dept varchar(15))  
BEGIN  
select  dept into in_dept from info where nam=in_name;  
END$$  
DELIMITER ;
```

My table

ID । nam    । dept

1 । sakib । cse    ।

2 । sakib । math   ।

when i give sakib then show "Result consisted of more than one row"
Although i have used DISTINCTROW,but same error shown
I have a query,is it possible only primary key (such as where id=in_id)?

Comment: You should only tag the DBMS you are using. sql-server <> mysql

Comment: thank you,but I am novice,so I have to face such kind of problem.

Comment: huh? The comment I made was that you tagged your question as sql-server but it is obvious you are not using sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your procedure check if "sakib" already exists, then you can use "limit 1":

```
select  dept into in_dept from info where nam=in_name LIMIT 1
```

It is enough to appear once to know that it exists :)

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT only gives you distinct rows. You need one row as result. So try this

```
SELECT dept into in_dept FROM info
   WHERE id IN ( SELECT  MIN(id)
                        FROM info where nam=in_name
             );
```

Comment: it is not possible to show more than one row? your answer show just one row output.but i want two row output.

Comment: Yes, with this kind of procedure you use can only return one value not a cursor to fetch more than one value.

Comment: it is also not possible more than one for column?

Comment: Just use more than one OUT in your  PROCEDURE `useOUT`(..., out in_dept varchar(15), OUT more1 varchar(10), OUT more2 varchar(10))